# cross platform library for interacting with USB devices in Java

Tags: java, usb, cross-platform

**Any API or library for USB interaction in Java in which the functions I will use to write will need not be changed as the platform they run on changes? Such that my app will run regardless on Windows, Linux, and Mac?**

The work that will be done by my app is basically

- getting the name of the USB device
- be able to tell if the device is still docked to the computer before the user logs off
- eject the usb device [well, not physically literally, that would be absurd] like Safely Remove of Windows.
- detect in real time the amount of space used up and space free on the usb device.

I found  on [javax.usb - JSR080 project](http://javax-usb.sourceforge.net/)
But at their page, the say:

`javax-usb-ri-windows : This is an ABANDONED Windows implementation. it does not work, it needs a kernel driver.`

And : `The OS-independent Reference Implementation contains a common partial implementation of javax.usb`

I just need an API that is cross platform and.. well just read the first line.

I also tried looking at libusb for C++, and its Python wrapper PyUSB, [I love Python, had to check that]. But the client needs code in Java.

Answer (score 0):

JVM does not has that kind of control over host OS. The only way is to run shell commands (different for each platform) with sufficient privileges , and parse the results (again, per platform). This definitely involves different code for different platforms.

Comment: brilliant idea..

but, can you advise me how to go about "safely removing" the usb device on all platforms? that will surely require some OS specific code?

Comment: @ronnieaka Safely removing is actually `unmount` operation, which makes device inaccessible for read/write _before_ it is physically disconnected. This avoids data corruption. On Linux its done with `umount` command. Don't know about windows.

Comment: @ronnieaka: something important: `umount` is only useful when you want to detach a filesystem. In general it has no relation whatsoever with USB - it would be useless if the USB device was not a storage device (webcam, barcode reader, fingerprint sensor...) or even if a USB storage device was used in an unconventional manner (e.g. as a DM or LVM component device, let alone as a swap device...)

Comment: well that complicates things. i was assuming just pendrives or usb interfaces of mobiles [micro-usb].

Anyways I guess there would be a workaround. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

**Take a look at [JavaHIDAPI](https://code.google.com/p/javahidapi/)**

This is a cross-platform Human Interface Device (HID) library that works on Windows, Mac and Linux. It provides all the native libraries for each and has an easy to use interface within Java. Documentation is a little sparse, but it should get you up and running fairly quickly.